# Fade in Multiple Divs When Each is Loaded

Tags: jquery, load, this

I'm trying to have multiple divs fade in when the content of each is done loading. Can't seem to get it to work.

```
   $(function() {
    $(".postphoto").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn(); });
   });
```

There are multiple divs with the same class, and I need to fade each in when they are ready. Any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery docs. Emphasis, mine.

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to **any element
>   associated with a URL**: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

So unless it's one of those elements described above, there's not a good way to tell when data for a specific div has loaded, the document.ready fires when the DOM has finished loading, excluding images.

Comment: Thanks Interstellar. Looks like just loading the images may be the best bet.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using the [imagesLoaded plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) to check if each image has loaded and then fade it in when successful.

The plugin also has the benefit of allowing for cached images.